# Is it Possible to change the Default Margins of Browser through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, printing, stylesheet

I want to change the default margins of Browser through JavaScript because I want to print the  displayed document on page but the margins are different on different browser??? plz help me to change default margins of browser. if you have any solution tell me.

Comment: "plz help me" is not needed to say. It looks unprofessional and this is an Q&A site already.

Comment: @Dykam comon - there's nothing unprofessional in saying "please".

Comment: @Anurag - But there is about 'plz'

Comment: @Govind - lol, I'm not here to take sides, I was arguing about the issue.

Comment: As @zipcodeman says, it's the "plz".

Comment: @Dykam @zipcoderman Although I prefer "please" to "plz", I wouldn't take my guns out if the latter is used. It's just changing times - http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=+site:stackoverflow.com+www.stackoverflow.com+plz&sa=X&ei=8C8PTJDgJJP2NciD-dgM&ved=0CBcQ2AQ

Comment: My itchies came from the fact that generally when I encounter "plz" it are whining kids too lazy took luuk it up themselfes. But I don't think that's the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to your page, and probably to all of your pages/projects.
This way you should be able to eliminate **all differencies** in default style values amongst  browsers.

Comment: you're welcome... yeah i have that from Stackoverflow :) see edit

Answer (score 3):

Not javascript, but if you are looking for specific styles to use for printing you can use:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />`

where `print.css` would contain something like

```
* { margin:0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("body").css("margin","0");
});
```

Using CSS

```
body { margin:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
body, html { margin:0 }
```

or

```
* { margin:0 }
```

or look into CSS reset. Would recommend this over JavaScript.